# Running hazelcast as embedded cache

Tags: spring, hazelcast

I have added hazelcast to my application, I am using spring boot. 
I am running it embedded in the application and now i am going to deploy this application to two different servers and there is going to be a load balancer in front of the server.  My question is how can i make the two cache sync with each other.

I can not find good information about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have nothing to do to synchronize the caches. If the nodes see each others, then all datas pushed in hazelcast are distributed in the cluster.

By default, the nodes discovers themselves through multicast. You can configure others methods of discoveries, like for example unicast, or jclouds.

see [this documentation](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.6/manual/html-single/index.html#discovering-cluster-members)